# "Freshwater" as opposed to salty water

Tags: etymology, nouns

I'm curious to find out why we talk of ***freshwater*** (or *fresh water*) when we refer to water with a very limited amount of salt dissolved in it.

Looking at various sources, both online and in books, I have learnt that the term ***sweetwater*** may also be used.

Do you know the origin of the expression and is ***sweetwater*** a valid alternative?

Comment: You seem to ask 'What is fresh about freshwater?'

Comment: In a sense, because it could not depend on water being cool. However, zpletan seems to have found an Old English term to justify "fresh"

Comment: _Sweetwater_ is not commonly used. It's most appropriate in historical contexts.

Comment: The analogue of *sweetwater* is used in a number of other languages: http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1071437

Comment: @Paola - You are capable to ask questions which are better than mine! +1

Comment: Don't use 'sweetwater', nobody will know what you're talking about, they'll think you added sugar to your drinking water. Use 'freshwater'.

Comment: @Carlo_R. Thank you, Carlo, both for the upvotes and for the appreciation. My questions are not particularly intelligent (I can assure you that I've read a few which I wish I had asked myself). Yours are different (I suppose we have a different background and age), but some are quite interesting. (Note that you should say "capable of asking questions"... )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NOAD identifies the etymology of *fresh*:

> ORIGIN Old English *fersc* [not salt, fit for drinking,] superseded in Middle English by forms from Old French ***freis***, ***fresche***; both ultimately of Germanic origin and related to Dutch ***vers*** and German ***frisch***.

---

*Sweetwater*, I would assume, is at this point (don't know about originally; cf. @BarrieEngland's answer) the antonym of *saltwater*, and therefore synonymous with *freshwater*.

Comment: No, [*sweetwater*](https://www.wordnik.com/words/sweetwater) is water that is suitable for drinking. There are reasons water might not be drinkable, even if it isn't salty.

Answer (score 6):

The OED’s earliest citation for ‘fresh water’ is 1528, in the phrase ‘the best freshe water fyshe’. ‘Sweet water’ appears around the middle of the sixteenth century, in the sense of ‘a sweet-smelling liquid preparation’. It is first used to mean fresh water in 1608.

Comment: Your OED must be much better than mine, as I couldn't find any reference to origins or comparisons between the two expressions

Comment: @Paola: OED online: http://www.oed.com/

Comment: Expanding on @Barrie's answer, the OED's oldest citation of this sense of "fresh" dates to c893 in Orosious' _History_:  (Eufrates) is mæst eallra ferscra wætera.  The full etymology is specifically listed as "obscure", but roughly corresponds to zpletan's answer.

Comment: @SimonJester: Quite right. I looked only under 'fresh water', not 'fresh'. Surprising there's not some kind of cross reference.

Answer (score 0):

My contention has always been that:

Rain water reaches the ground, is partly utilized, and eventually flows into the sea.

Therefore, water freshly obtained from rain, from water-bodies or ground water is fresh and potable, unlike that which has washed out into the sea to become salt water heavy with minerals.