# "Fresh water" and "Sweet water" - are these phrases completely equivalent?

Tags: differences

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Freshwater” as opposed to salty water](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/64617/freshwater-as-opposed-to-salty-water)

I know that non-salt water is called [fresh water](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresh_water).
But also from time to time I've seen the expression `sweet water`, for example:

> Lake Geneva is smaller than many other European lakes, however, with
>   its average depth of 153 meters, it is unusually deep, and happens to
>   be, by volume, the largest **sweet water** reserve in Western-Europe.

Can we claim that these two expressions are completely equivalent?

Comment: There are almost 6M instances of **freshwater** in Google Books. Almost all of the 600 or so for **sweetwater** are actually using it as a placename. So even if some people are familiar with using *sweet* to mean *fresh, not salty*, I definitely wouldn't say they're "equivalent".

Comment: In other languages fresh water is expressed by the literal translation of "sweet water". It's a mis-translation in English though, so while the intention is identical, one is correct and one is a mistake. That difference is enough not to make them equivalent.

Comment: @tenfour, than, it turns out that this question is not completely identical to that that is supposed to be exact duplicate )